# Imagem não responsiva

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em ecras maiores a imagem duplica e quero que isso não aconteça.

Estou a usar o seguinte código:

```
background-image: url("../assetsimages/book.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;  
    max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
```

Mesmo assim não está a funcionar

Answer (score 2):

Para nao repetir use:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Ou

```
background-size: 100% auto; //Largura e altura respectivamente
```

Comment: tentei e não dá veja: http://ami.responsivedesign.is/?url=http%3A%2F%2Funn-w17015779.newnumyspace.co.uk

Answer (score 2):

Esse código deve dar certo. Se não der é porque tem alguma outra classe sobrescrevendo a sua.

Documentação sobre o background: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/

Repare que para funcionar tem que determinar uma altura para o `<body>` e para a `<div>`

Veja abaixo o exemplo cobrindo a 50% da tela sem repetir, mesmo a dive tendo 100%

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.bg {
    background-image: url("http://placecage.com/800/600");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    background-size: 50%;
    background-color: aqua;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

tente esse codigo
Há a propriedade background-size: cover;
Que faz com que o background preencha todo o tamanho do elemento

```
background-image: url("../assetsimages/book.jpg");
background-position:center center;
background-size:cover;
max-width:100%;
height: auto;
```

Comment: http://ami.responsivedesign.is/?url=http%3A%2F%2Funn-w17015779.newnumyspace.co.uk continua sem dar!